# Access a nested array in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6

So i am attempting to access an Array of objects within a JSON object. I have an API that i am grabbing data from. The API was initially an XML and i converted it to a JSON object, however one i have dashes in my element names. (dang), but i also want to pull from the list of products. Below is an example of the API structure.

[image]

The goal is to get the list of products from the API.

Thanks to PXLJoy i was able to come up with the following solution. Note: I am using RXJS 6, therefore everything is wrapped in a pipe.

```
  public getData(): Observable<any> {
    const cjData = this.http.get('/assets/json/name.json');
    return cjData.pipe(map(res => res['cj-api'].products[0].product));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing properties in JSON can be done with `[]` [square brackets](https://javascript.info/object#square-brackets), these are often used for variable keys, i.e

```js
const key = 'cj-api';
const obj = response[key];
```

or string keys, i.e

```js
const obj = response['cj-api'];
```

With that said, based on your screenshot, you could get the `products` array by going:

```js
// response is the object as shown in your screenshot.
response['cj-api'].products[0].product; // your target array
```

Comment: You rock. Thanks! I overthink to many things. I started with square brackets but i guess i just needed someone to say the same. Thanks again.

Comment: @KevinSummersill glad I could help :) remember to mark this the answer if it solved your problem so other people can learn!

Comment: @pxlijoy - Done. Thanks again!